# How to Enable Right-Clicking on Web Sites That Block It

Tags: javascript, html

Though it’s less common these days, many sites still use JavaScript or an HTML attribute to disable right-clicking on their pages. It’s a practice we hope goes away, but in the meantime, it’s not too hard to get around those restrictions.

Comment: Cool. So what's the question?

Comment: how to enable right click  on web site ? those website having right click disabled .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to browser settings, then disable Javascript, and reload the page. Right click will work.